# How use configStore in Redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

createStore is working fine. but in v18 react, configStore is needed. How use configStore with redux-saga middleware

`

```
const SagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(SagaMiddleware));
SagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
        <ToastContainer position="top-center" />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>
);
```

`

Comment: ##### redux-starter-kit does not include sagaMiddleware by default [1]. You'll need to add it to the middleware list and initialize the sagas yourself.


```
# I hope this will work

Comment: I have the answer ready but can't answer it because of the stackoverflow rules. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

###### redux-starter-kit does not include sagaMiddleware by default [1]. You'll need to add it to the middleware list and initialize the sagas yourself.

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from 'redux-starter-kit'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'
import { initSagas } from '../initSagas'

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware(), sagaMiddleware]
})
initSagas(sagaMiddleware);
```

#### I hope this will work for you

#### if not let me know

Comment: Now all the things happening twice, ie, console.log, api calls etc

Comment: yes it will happen but can you share the messages and let me see what is causing them